# Change jobs to earn more, or stay the same to gain experience?

Tags: salary, job-offer, work-experience

The truth is that I think I have little experience, I'm working for less than 2 years in the same company, have no other professional experience. Before that I was a researcher for three years during college and have some published articles, nothing else.

What happens now is that I'm in now earning the salary X + poor benefits. And I have job offer from another company, much larger, multinational to earn about X + 25% + better benefits.

In my current place of work(small company, a lot of freedom but very old and old concepts of wages) I am currently the guy who does critical tasks that make and change entire systems, I can say that they trust me on that too and I've done it several times. And as I have my past in research, give me a lot of interesting tasks to use new technologies and different from those used normally. I evolved a lot in that time that work here and they promised me to continue working with more new things, different projects and other critical projects, but I still feel very badly paid.

That other company, multinational, I do not know what I can really expect, do not want to miss the chance to learn at that speed I'm learning in the current company and just be a "byte writer" in the new one, but those 25% actually make a difference in my case.

What is best for someone with little experience as me? More experience (and the chance to work with new things) or more money and a better position (and of course the chance to learn different processes and other "new" things in a new company)?

Sorry for the guest, but my real user has my real name on it.

Comment: Questions asking about [which job to take](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2695#2695) are off-topic here.

Comment: I'd lean towards the better offer, personally. Do you require new skills of a specific nature which can only be learned in industry, or can you just buy some Sams/Person Ed books and teach yourself the skills/languages?

Comment: @DavidK its not about which job, is more about, Exp vs Money? what is better to the new ones in the market...

Comment: It still comes down to a question that only you can make. Everyone has different values and priorities. We can't tell you which is more valuable, because we are not you.

Comment: "Questions asking for advice on what to do are not [practical answerable questions](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)."

Comment: Do you need Starbucks coffee? Or is homemade Folgers adequate? If it's the latter, buckle down a few more years. If it's the former, enjoy the fancy designer coffee and slightly less sexy new job.  IMNSHO

Comment: If you are the type of person with the skills and the drive to not just be a "byte-writer" at a big company then you will be able to learn and accomplish far more than you ever will at a small company. OTOH, if you don't have the drive and skills then stay at the small company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you happy?

When I was young my brother-in-law told me that the trick is to find a job that doesn't make you hate waking up in the morning. Okay there are exceptions, I'd happily sit in a room and be routinely electrocuted for five years if there was a $1,000,000 paycheck waiting for me at the end of the day, but don't gamble friends and a good environment for a small bump in cash.

The most amount of money I was ever offered for a job was with this company where I'd be sat next to a guy who hasn't moved up the company structure for 15 years, coding software that looks like it belongs in the early 90's and having everything I create seen as a 'business cost' whilst the sales team has monthly champagne parties.

They offered me even more money when I declined, and couldn't understand why that didn't change my mind.

I won't pretend to say that philosophy applies to everyone ever, I'm very fortunate in that I have no dependents and an industry open enough where I can be sure to find another offer with someone else. But if you're in the position where you have a choice, then don't see the equation as money > experience, but rather happiness A > happiness B

Answer (score 0):

If you believe that you deserve a better salary, you can ask your current employer for this. If they deny, you can go for the other job.